# Two separate applications, two databases, one IOC. How to share membership?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, circular-reference

I am making a website and have two databases, one for my application, and another for an external application. By external, I mean it is an opensource application that I want to work with. The application is [MVCForum](http://www.mvcforum.com/)

This external application already has membership integrated. It uses dependency injection (Unity) and uses Entity Framework. Obviously I don't want to destroy the project and would like to be able to have my application run alongside the MVCForum so that when/if it ever gets updated, I can run the updates without too much trouble and without it affecting my application.

So, here is the problem:

I have a MembershipUser class part of an application, call it externamApp.

```
namespace MVCForum.Domain.DomainModel
{
    public partial class MembershipUser : Entity
        {
            public MembershipUser()
            {
                Id = GuidComb.GenerateComb();
            }
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<MembershipRole> Roles { get; set; }

            //I need to have this. A user has one or many trips
            public virtual IList<Trip> Trips{ get; set; }

        }
 }
```

I also have my own app, let's call it myApp. Within my app, I have a class called Trip.

```
namespace MyApp.Domain.DomainModel.TripModels
{
    public partial class Trip : Entity
    {
        public Trip()
        {
            Id = GuidComb.GenerateComb();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual MembershipUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual TCCategory Category { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As you can see, MembershipUser has a property:

```
public virtual IList<Trip> Trips{ get; set; }
```

This is because a user can have one to many trips...
You can also see that Trip has a property:

```
public virtual MembershipUser User { get; set; }
```

But, I would also like to have a user attached to my Trip class. 
When Entity Framework pulls an object from the database, it links with that object all the sub-objects. For example, when it pulls out MembershipUser, it will have all the roles of that user attached - because of this property (and the mapping obviously):

```
public virtual IList<MembershipRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

I realize that this is a circular reference, but I am hoping someone with more knowledge can offer a good suggestion or perhaps even a solution.

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using ? forms?

Comment: @DiogoCunha Yeah, forms.

Comment: I answered the question you ask for, but i can't get if you just want to share the classes or you want to share the authentication too, can you answer that one for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said and well you have a circular dependency, it is not good to have such dependencies and you should not create solutions with that kind of approach.

The first solution that comes to my mind is that you **create a new project (a library)** that contains information about your membership (I suggest you to go further and create a Data library containing all the data related classes), that way you can reference that project from both your applications and and avoid the circular dependency.